# Connect PostgreSQL by private ip in gcp PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I have created a PostgreSQL database in gcp but it only has private ip  no public ip is being assigned. How can I migrate my old database to that new one, and how can I connect it with the project?

I tried assigning the public ip but do not have permission to do so

Answer (score 1):

IDK about your previous DB instance, but these are general options I could think of:

1. Connect from inside your Virtual Private Network. Like, a GCE VM.
2. Use a [language connector](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy)
3. For manual tasks like importing previous DB dump, use [cloudsqlproxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy)
4. Gather permission you need and [associate a public IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip). IMO less preferable unless you must. When there is a public IP, the measures must be taken to secure it.